# "Extract" mutation name from an "OperationDefinitionNode" Object?

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, graphql-php

I am using the `webonyx/graphql-php` and Laravel.

I have a single `middleware` that "catches" all `graphql` requests and I would like
to apply some logic to filter some `requests` depending if the `request` is a `mutation` and which `mutation` it is.

I "intersect" the graphql query (similar to this one) where the mutation **storeCC** is being called

```
...
"query":"mutation ($input: Card!) {
  storeCC(input: $input) {
    id
    firstName
    lastName
...
```

Then parse the `query` using the `GraphQL\Language\Parser` into a `GraphQL\Language\AST\OperationDefinitionNode` object

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS48n.png

---

My question is then How can I know the `mutation` name (**storeCC** is this case.) using the `OperationDefinitionNode`? Is there another way to extract the mutation name (**storeCC**) that I am invoking from the `query string`?